# Setting up virtual machine and applications

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v, exchange-2019

I 've got following collection of features installed in virtual machines

| Server name | Feature Installed |
| --- | --- |
| E-Dom | Active Directory, NFS File Share |
| E-Coll | Exchange Server, Sharepoint, PBX Server |
| E-Sec | NPS, Certificate Authority |
| E-Art | Wireshark |

I could use some recommendations whether each of these features can be added to same VM or another VM/ a dedicated VM is more necessary? For example, I've have learned can that active directory and exchange server is not recommended to reside on same VM. Same goes for Certificate Authority mixed with Active Directory but I am not sure why.
Same question goes for Sharepoint server alongside Exchange Server
And PBX Server alongside Exchange Server.

I would think PBX server needs it's dedicated VM but it's critical nature can be equally matched with Exchange server, none of them can afford to lose internet connection/ go down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for how to couple those together.

- **E-Dom Active Directory:** Single / On its own. Provides stability of your network if issues come up with other services used throughout your network.
- **NFS File Share:** Can be mixed with Sharepoint
- **E-Coll Exchange Server:** Single / On its own.
- **Sharepoint:** Can be mixed with NFS Share
- **PBX Server:** Deff on its own, you may need to reboot this from time to time.
- **E-Sec NPS:** IF it's a Microsoft NPS, can work with AD. Otherwise Alone.
- **Certificate Authority:** This can be the DC, Not sure why they told you otherwise? I would do some research on that one just in case but we do it all the time and never had issues.
- **E-Art Wireshark:** On its own

Pretty much any databases you want to keep running on their own except for some limited exceptions. Active Directory is a database, so while you can even pair it with the NPS server, it is a better idea to keep the NPS on its own. However this depends on budgets and licensing and whatnot, they could run together since they are both Microsoft products and NPS relied on the directory at the end of the day.

Then you have your other network services servers, NFS, SharePoint, PBX, exchange, etc. The trick to these other servers is that they could need a reboot from time to time or run into issues and you want your company to be able to keep working if per se your e-mail server is trashed tonight. So you separate these, that way one issue with one thing won't cover 2 other systems, etc. Limits your scope of impact when something goes wrong.

On the same note, your NPS and Wireshark server could work together as well if they are running on the same OS type, just like file-sharing services (SharePoint, NFS) could be paired together. More reliable if you separate everything but again, depends on your budget and cost.

Comment: Thanks for your answers,

Comment: Is it safe to install Certificate Authority onto Edge Server (not mentioned in question)? Would Windows Server Essentials be good enough to run Exchange and Active Directory as my users grow?